# Implicit typeconversion and polymorphy

Tags: c#

I'm currently building a small library for state machines (yeah, there are lots of those, but I'm in it for the fun). Now, I've encountered an interesting problem.

Assume, that a given statemachine accepts events of a certain type. If we were to parse a protocol this might, e.g. be characters. So in a certain state the character 'a' might lead to a new state, while all other characters (or a group of characters) remain in that state (e.g. Receive the payload of a packet, while no ETX was received).

My statemachine is defined similar to how Boost::MSM does it, i.e: a list of transitions with the events that trigger them:

```
        var S1 = new BasicTState<char>("S1");
        var S2 = new BasicTState<char>("S2");

        var transitions = new[]
        {
            new TTransition<char>{from = S1, to = S2, evt = 'b', guard = null },
            new TTransition<char>{from = S2, to = S1, evt = 'a', guard = null },
        };

        // The type parameter denotes the type of event, that is to be accepted.
        // the second parameter is the initial state!
        var sm = new TStateMachine<char>(transitions, S1);  

        sm.Event('b');

        Assert.AreEqual(sm.ActiveState, S2);
```

So far so good - now. Given the situation, where I want several e.g. characters, to match to the same statetransition I'm a bit stuck. The naive way would be to define a statetransition for each and every character to accept - which is tedious and errorprone. What I would like to do is use "Matcher" objects that will do that job, e.g.:

```
            var transitions = new[]
        {
            new TTransition<Matcher<char>>{from = S1, to = S2, evt = new Matcher<char>(new[] {'c', 'd'}), guard = null },
            new TTransition<Matcher<char>>{from = S2, to = S1, evt = new Matcher<char>(new[] {'e', 'f'}), guard = null },

        };
```

To get this to work I've defined implicit conversions for the matcher, so that I can still generate events like in the above example, i.e. "`sm.Event('c')`". This works just fine. However now I'm in a situation where my statemachine object must be of the type `TStateMachine<Matcher<char>>` which is obviously annoying since I now cannot use a simple notation for cases, where only one eventtype needs to be matched and I can only ever use a single type of matcher and the implicit typeconversion will always force me into this one type. Worse, I cannot hide the matcher behind an interface because the typeconversion won't play with that at all.

I'm aware, that I could solve the problem of matching single and multiple eventtypes easily using interfaces, but that would compromise the readability quite a bit (and, quite frankly, it's no fun to solve it that way). What I'm really interested in is, if there is any way to get polymorphy to play nicely with implicit typeconversion. I'd imagine ending up with something like:

```
    var transitions = new[]
    {
        new TTransition<char>{from = S1, to = S2, evt = 'b', guard = null },
        new TTransition<char>{from = S2, to = S1, evt = new Matcher<char>(new[] {'e', 'f'}), guard = null },
        new TTransition<char>{from = S2, to = S1, evt = new YetAnotherMatcherTypeIDontKnowAboutYet<char>(new YadaYadaObject()), guard = null }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the state itself need the generic type parameter? Why should the state need to know how it was triggered?

I would declare the transition type like this

```
public class Transition<TEvent>
{
    public BasicState From { get; set; }
    public BasicState To { get; set; }
    public Func<TEvent, bool> EventMatcher { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

and the state machine like this

```
public class StateMachine<TEvent>
{
    public StateMachine(Transition<TEvent>[] transitions, BasicState initialState)
    {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

and the transitions would always declare a matcher, even in the simple case where a single character is used

```
var transitions = new[]
{
    new Transition<char>{From = S1, To = S2, EventMatcher = c => c == 'b', Guard = null },
    new Transition<char>{From = S2, To = S1, EventMatcher = c => c == 'a', Guard = null },
};
```

If you need to match several characters you can write

```
new Transition<char>{From = S2, To = S1, EventMatcher = c => "ef".Contains(c), Guard = null }
```

Note, I've used [Lambda Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) (with the `=>` syntax).

I've omitted the "T" prefix from the type names, as this is not usual in C# (it's usual in Pascal). Also, properties should be in PascalCase, even in C# :-). See [Naming Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) on MSDN.

---

Alternatively, you could declare different types of transitions. They would be responsible for the matching themselves

```
public abstract class TransitionBase<TEvent>
    where TEvent : IEquatable<TEvent>
{
    public BasicState From { get; set; }
    public BasicState To { get; set; }
    public abstract bool DoesMatchEvent(TEvent event);
}

public class SingleEventTransition<TEvent> : TransitionBase<TEvent>
    where TEvent : IEquatable<TEvent>
{
    TEvent Event { get; set; }
    public override bool DoesMatchEvent(TEvent event)
    {
        return Event.Equals(event);
    }
}

public class MultiEventTransition<TEvent> : TransitionBase<TEvent>
    where TEvent : IEquatable<TEvent>
{
    TEvent[] Events { get; set; }
    public override bool DoesMatchEvent(TEvent event)
    {
        foreach (TEvent e in Events) {
            if (e.Equals(event)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Note that since you don't know the real type of `TEvent` in advance, you cannot work with it as if it was a `char`; however, you can specify a generic type constraint requiring the type to be equatable, i.e. to provide an `Equals` method. The basic types like `char`, `int`, `string` do. If you implement your own event type, you can implement the [`IEquatable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) interface yourself.

```
TransitionBase<char>[] transitions = new[]
{
    new SingleEventTransition<char>{From = S1, To = S2, Event = 'b', Guard = null },
    new MultiEventTransition<char>{From = S2, To = S1, Events = new TEvent[]{ 'e', 'f'},
                                   Guard = null },
};
```

Comment: I used the type parameter on the state in order to be able to use events with payloads that need to be processed from within an OnEnter/OnLeave Method of the state. 
Anyway: The solution to use a lambda is very charming and does indeed solve my problem :)
Thanks for the help.